# What is the bulk write limit of Firestore admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to implement a bulk import functionality for a web app that I am working on, and was wondering if there is a limit to how many "add's" that can be performed by a cloud function for firebase using admin SDK.

To be specific, I was wondering if firebase cloud function and the admin SDK is capable of doing something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    admin.firestore().collection("someLocation").add({
        time: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })
}
```

When I did similar thing with realtime database from the client, the data was entered only until like the first 100 entries.

Is this bulk upload type of thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Firestore [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), that allow up to 500 updates in the same operation. Other than that you're also limited by [Firestore quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). That is 2500 writes per second, and 20000 writes a day (for free tier).

Comment: About the 2500 per second limit, does a batch write count as 1 write, or what ever number of writes being performed?

Comment: Using batch writes streamlines the HTTP request flow and allows the client to optimize its request flow. Instead of sending a single request per write, it can send up to 500 writes at once. This greatly reduces request overhead (even as connections are reused). Please note that write limits are unaffected by this: You can perform 2500 writes/s per database, and 500 writes/s per collection.

Please also note that you can greatly optimize your code if you cache the instance that is returned from "admin.firestore()". This will allow us to share auth credentials and reduce initialization cost.

Comment: Firestore no longer limits the number of writes that can be passed to a Commit operation or performed in a transaction. Previously, the limit was 500. Limits for request size and the transaction time limit still apply. ([source](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes#March_29_2023))